# How do I create many variables, that depend on multiple conditions in R (akin to the array-function in SAS)

Tags: r, loops

I'm analyzing a time-use dataset, in which for every household member 144 columns indicate which activity they did in every 10-minute slot (i.e. from 08:00 to 08:10) and 144 columns indicate, if the partner was present at each interval and so on.

I'm trying to create two different types of variables.

1. I need to sum up the time, that one individual spent in some activities (e.g. one sum-variable for talking & eating, one for leisure) with and without the partner.

In SAS this worked with the use of arrays like this:

```
array main_men(*) main_men_1-main_men_144;
array partner_men(*) partner_men_1-partner_men_144;

sum_eating = 0;
do i=1 to 144; if main_men(i) in (100:200) & partner_men(i) in (0) 
then sum_eating = sum_eating + 10; end;
```

Therefore, each occurrence of the specific activity code AND the condition of the partner-presence in the same variable slot (1 to 144) was met, a new variable added +10 mins (since each occurrence stands for one 10-minute time slot.
In R it would suffice to *count* the occurrences that both conditions were met.

2. In order to do a sequence analysis, I also not only need sum-variables, but 144 new variables, that indicate, whether the individual was in leisure alone or with the partner, or was doing unpaid work etc.

So I need 144 variables for the 24.
Again, I only know the SAS-logic, but I want to ditch SAS completely und move over to R.

```
array seq(*) seq_1-seq_144;

do i=1 to 144; if main_men(i) in (200:399) and partner_men(i) in (0) 
then seq_paar(i)=1; end; 

do i=1 to 144; if main_men(i) in (200:399) and partner_men(i) in (1) 
then seq_paar(i)=2; end;
```

Here, I created 144 blank variables, that are 1 if the specific activity code occurred and the individual was alone (partner_men was 0) and are 0 if the code occurred, but the individual was with a partner.

I created a small sample of the dataset to make it hopefully much more clear and reproducible:

```
structure(list(id = c(11, 12, 17, 31, 35, 36, 41, 42, 47, 61), 
    men_main_55 = c(210, 210, 421, 992, 132, 622, 630, 466, 611, 
    969), men_main_56 = c(210, 210, 421, 992, 132, 622, 630, 
    466, 611, 969), men_main_57 = c(210, 210, 421, 992, 611, 
    622, 630, 466, 611, 969), men_main_58 = c(210, 210, 421, 
    131, 120, 622, 466, 466, 611, 641), men_main_59 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 452, 120, 622, 466, 466, 611, 641), men_main_60 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 452, 120, 622, 466, 466, 611, 641), wom_main_55 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 992, 411, 622, 421, 120, 641, 630), wom_main_56 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 992, 411, 622, 947, 120, 641, 630), wom_main_57 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 992, 611, 622, 947, 120, 641, 630), wom_main_58 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 998, 120, 622, 947, 421, 641, 630), wom_main_59 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 461, 120, 622, 421, 421, 641, 630), wom_main_60 = c(210, 
    210, 421, 461, 120, 622, 421, 421, 641, 630), partner_men_55 = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), partner_men_56 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), partner_men_57 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0), partner_men_58 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1
    ), partner_men_59 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), partner_men_60 = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), partner_wom_55 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), partner_wom_56 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0), partner_wom_57 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
    ), partner_wom_58 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), partner_wom_59 = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), partner_wom_60 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), label = "PAARZEIT_SEQ", 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried various *apply* and *loop* approaches but nothing worked.
Thanks!

Comment: can you add your expected output? also you have not defined `sum_eating`

Comment: you're right, I forgot to define the sum_eating variable.

Comment: My expected output for part 1) would be a variable for each individual that contains the number of occurrences that this condition is met. 

For part 2) I need 144 variables from 1 to 144 indicating if the individual had a specific activity code in the corresponding main_x variable AND had a 0 in the corresponding partner_men variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is inconsistent with your sample code (check the column names) and you haven't given us any expected output, so it's difficult to be sure of exactly what you want.

The fundamental difference between the view that SAS and R take of datasets/data frames is that SAS regards data as a collection of *rows*, whereas R regards data as a collection of *columns*: their views of the world are perpendicular to each other.  Therefore, by simply translating your SAS code into R you are making life difficult for yourself.  The difficulty is particularly apparent in your second question.  If you shift your world view from rows to columns as you move from SAS to R, you will save yourself much pain and effort in the long run.

[By the way, it is bad form to ask two questions on one post.]

Adopting [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data practices will also be beneficial, whether you work in SAS or R: the principles are generic.

That said, to answer your first question:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sumEatingMen=10*rowSums(across(starts_with("men_main_"), ~. %in% 100:200)),
    sumEatingWom=10*rowSums(across(starts_with("wom_main_"), ~. %in% 100:200))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(id, sumEatingMen, sumEatingWom)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      id sumEatingMen sumEatingWom
   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1    11            0            0
 2    12            0            0
 3    17            0            0
 4    31           10            0
 5    35           50           30
 6    36            0            0
 7    41            0            0
 8    42            0           30
 9    47            0            0
10    61            0            0
```

To answer the question in a R-like way, first convert your data to a tidy format:

```
df1a <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=c(starts_with("men"), starts_with("wom")),
    names_pattern="(.*)_main_(.*)",
    values_to="Activity",
    names_to=c("Sex", "Index")
  ) %>% 
  select(id, Sex, Index, Activity)
df1b <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=c(starts_with("partner")),
    names_pattern="partner_(.*)_(.*)",
    values_to="Partner",
    names_to=c("Sex", "Index")
  ) %>% 
  select(id, Sex, Index, Partner)
df1 <- df1a %>% full_join(df1b, by=c("id", "Sex", "Index"))
df1
# A tibble: 120 x 5
      id Sex   Index Activity Partner
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    11 men   55         210       0
 2    11 men   56         210       0
 3    11 men   57         210       0
 4    11 men   58         210       0
 5    11 men   59         210       0
 6    11 men   60         210       0
 7    11 wom   55         210       0
 8    11 wom   56         210       0
 9    11 wom   57         210       0
10    11 wom   58         210       0
# … with 110 more rows
```

An answer to your question is then

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id, Sex) %>% 
   summarise(sumEating=10*sum(Activity %in% 100:200), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 20 x 3
      id Sex   sumEating
 * <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1    11 men           0
 2    11 wom           0
 3    12 men           0
 4    12 wom           0
 5    17 men           0
 6    17 wom           0
 7    31 men          10
 8    31 wom           0
 9    35 men          50
10    35 wom          30
<10 rows omitted>
```

Notice how much more generic, compact and readable this solution is compared to the SAS-like solution.

To answer your second question in a tidy fashion:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(unpaidWorkWithPartner=Activity %in% 200:399 & Partner == 1)
# A tibble: 120 x 6
      id Sex   Index Activity Partner unpaidWorkWithPartner
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>                
 1    11 men   55         210       0 FALSE                
 2    11 men   56         210       0 FALSE                
 3    11 men   57         210       0 FALSE                
 4    11 men   58         210       0 FALSE                
 5    11 men   59         210       0 FALSE                
 6    11 men   60         210       0 FALSE                
 7    11 wom   55         210       0 FALSE                
 8    11 wom   56         210       0 FALSE                
 9    11 wom   57         210       0 FALSE                
10    11 wom   58         210       0 FALSE                
# … with 110 more rows
```

If I've understood your post correctly, no one did any unpaid work with their partner at any time in your sample dataset.

It will be possible to answer your second question in a SAS-like manner, but I suspect the solution will be long, fragile and awkward.  I certainly don't have the time to investigate any further.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time and the answer! I realize that I was not too precise in asking the question(s) and providing a clear expected output. 

I'm trying to move from SAS to R, so the tidy-approach is what I was looking for, thanks for the insights!. Both approaches worked flawlessly.